# Cartilaginous mermaid or bony mermaid best for adapting underwater?

Tags: internal-consistency, mythical-creatures, underwater, merfolk

What are the differences between a blue whale and a mega-mouth? Size and ... their skeletal structure, of course. A dolphin is extremely agile in water and is excellent at hunting for fish but it could not match the prowess of Great White in the open water. Intelligence can only get you so far because the Great White is many times larger than a dolphin but of lesser weight; the explanation lies in their cartilage which has advantages over bone.

I need my mermaid to escape from its jaws so which kind of backbone should my mermaid grow?

Comment: By "mega mouth", do you mean a Great White shark? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_white_shark

Comment: I think you need to clarify this question

Comment: As you point out, there are examples of both types of skeleton in the ocean, so without putting a little more thought into the question there isn't a good answer. Say it has bone, it could still escape using other means besides raw speed.